# Loading thread for Windows Form Application?

Tags: winforms

I am currently developing a windows form application as the subscriber for my WCF service and a asp.net application as the publisher for the service.

Whenever I launch the service or the client, and attempt to "Connect" (AKA subscribe) to the service, it would take awhile to load before it displays a successful message or exception handling. And while the thing "loads", the windows form sort of "hangs" temporary until the thing loads finish.

Is it possible to create a loading effect while they are "loading" to feedback to the user? Anyone can guide me on how to actually start developing this effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use asynchronous service calls. Before calling the asynchronous call you can show graphical representation of this and in the completion of the asynchronous call you can stop displaying the progress of the call.

Refer to this link to know how you can [call the wcf service asynchronously](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/03/18/making-asynchronous-service-calls-from-a-winform-client.aspx).